# Mobile responsive problem in reactJs navbar

Tags: reactjs, navigation, navbar

I'm a beginner to ReactJs this is a portfolio site. I am trying to mobile responsive navbar(Topbar). I am using SCSS here.

- **This is the mobile view.**

  [Mobile preview -1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N4SS.png)

  [Mobile preview -2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tosNn.png)
- **This is the desktop view.**

  [Desktop preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LS0o.png)

> The problem - I want to hide to be hidden in desktop view. I hide the
> hamburger but the side menu is still appears.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using css, then use media queries in the css file of your project with the min-width and set the class css to display: none.
So it is something like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
.mobile-menu-class{
display: none ; 
}
```

Comment: bro I'm using scss

Comment: Any way I solve it, Thanks for the help :)